# Need to run Mono (Xamarin Studio) Web Service on Linux

Tags: linux, xamarin-studio

Lately I have built a sample `ASP.NET` Web Service using Xamarin Studio. 
I need to run this Web Service on Linux OS. What steps should I take to accomplish this task?

My Xamarin Studio version is `5.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging you can run the service straight from the IDE (MonoDevelop) or use XSP to run it from command line. To configure as a service you have a few options that are described in detail on the Mono site:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/

What suits you the best is up to you but my suggestion would be to start with XSP and then Nginx. If those don't suit your needs then try the other alternatives.

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/nginx/